# Setting Console Font in C on Windows 10

Tags: c, windows, winapi, windows-console

I am trying to change the size of console font in my console application during runtime.

Looking into the Windows documentation, I found the following functions:
`GetCurrentConsoleFont` (and `GetCurrentConsoleFontEx`)
and `SetCurrentConsoleFontEx`.

```
CONSOLE_FONT_INFO prevFontInfo = {sizeof(prevFontInfo)};
GetCurrentConsoleFont( GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FALSE, &prevFontInfo 
);

CONSOLE_FONT_INFO fontInfo = {0};
//fontInfo.cbSize = sizeof(prevFontInfo);
fontInfo.dwFontSize.X = 30;
fontInfo.dwFontSize.Y = 70;
//fontInfo.FontWeight = 700;

SetCurrentConsoleFontEx( GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FALSE, &fontInfo );

... (Some Irrelevant Code Here)

SetCurrentConsoleFontEx( GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FALSE, 
&prevFontInfo );
```

Currently I am getting the following warnings:

> implicit declaration of function 'GetCurrentConsoleFont'

and

> implicit declaration of function 'SetCurrentConsoleFont'

I tried using `GetConsoleFontEx` (the reason `FontWeight` and `cbSize` are commented out) to no prevail. I used `CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX` as well, which resulted in the following error:

> Unkown type name 'CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX'

I read that it is necessary to use the following:

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500
```

I also tried several variations of this (0x0502, 0x0600, ect.), but nothing seemed to change the warnings/errors.

I include the following windows headers, and I compile with -lkernel32.

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500

#include <windows.h>
#include <Wincon.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
```

I wish to change the font size in C for the Windows terminal at runtime.
How do I do that? Why is this not working?

Comment: your problem with how you include windows headers files (and this you not show)

Comment: An `implicit declaration of function` error probably means you're missing a header file. [According to the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683176(v=vs.85).aspx), you should have `#include <Windows.h>` and `#include <Wincon.h>` at the top of your file. You also need to link your code with the `Kernel32` library. Have you done that yet?

Comment: @RbMm Awh, yes. Thank you, I forgot to include those in my question, they were in my compiled code. I updated my post.

Comment: Show your include. Do you have other `#include` before `#include <wincon.h>`, etc.

Comment: what version of sdk you use ? usually at very begin of `windows.h` exist `#include <sdkddkver.h>` - look in this file `#if !defined(_WIN32_WINNT) && !defined(_CHICAGO_)
#define  _WIN32_WINNT   *** #endif` - what default version ? and not need direct `#include <Wincon.h>` - it included indirect via `windows.h`

Comment: @RbMm Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7 SDK

Comment: look in windows.h exist #include <sdkddkver.h> ? if yes look in this file how `_WIN32_WINNT`  defined by default

Comment: Yes, #include <sdkddkver.h> does exist and in sdkddkver.h _WIN32_WINNT is defined as follows : #if !defined(_WIN32_WINNT) && !defined(_CHICAGO_)
#define  _WIN32_WINNT   0x0A00
#endif

Comment: are you use precompiled headers ? something strange - you use sdk 10. you not need `#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500` - by default it will be `#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0A00`

Comment: @squeamishossifrage: According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683176.aspx), you need to `#include <Windows.h>`. You do **not** need to `#include <Wincon.h>`.

Comment: So I should try sdk 10 instead of sdk 4.7? I believe I'm using precompiled headers, how do I check?

Comment: or may be you early defined `_WIN32_WINNT` say in project settings. try next macros `#include <windows.h>
#define _astring(x) #x
#define astring(x) _astring(x)
#define showmacro(x) __pragma(message(__FILE__ astring((__LINE__): \nmacro\t)#x" expand to\n" astring(x)))
showmacro(_WIN32_WINNT)` - what will be output ?

Comment: @IInspectable I tried without wincon.h initially, I added it just in case.

Comment: `I believe I'm using precompiled headers` - if you use precompiled headers - the first include in file - must be this precompile header (usually `#include <stdafx.h>` ) - look in project settings - c++

Comment: If you are using precompiled headers and the first non-comment line in any compilation unit does not include the header file used to create the PCH will result in a compiler **error**, not a warning. If you do not get any errors, and you aren't including the header file used to create the PCH, you aren't using precompiled headers.

Comment: Are precompiled headers necessary here? I will read more details online, they are fairly new to me.

Comment: No, precompiled headers are never necessary. They are a performance optimization. Since you noted that you are linking with `-lkernel32`, I assume you aren't using Visual Studio. Whenever you use a non-standard development tool you need to explicitly state this.

Comment: Start with a simple test program written in notepad. You should only need to include "Windows.h". Start with `CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX fontInfo = {sizeof(CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX)}`. Fill it with the current values via `GetCurrentConsoleFontEx`; set the new font height in `fontInfo.dwFontSize.Y`; and set this back via `SetCurrentConsoleFontEx`. If it doesn't compile and link without errors or warnings, you'll have to figure out how to use your build environment properly. It works effortlessly with VC++ cl.exe on the command line.

Comment: Very well, I will play around with things and see what is wrong with my environment. Thank you for everyone's help.